# Keep entity-references clean without saving to database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Given the following:

2 Entites (`Address` <-(m:1)-> `City`), an `Address` has one `City` (FK by their Id)

```
class Address
{
    public Guid AddressId {get;set;}
    public Guid AddressCityId  {get;set;}

    public City CityEntity  {get;set;}

    public string CityName { get { return CityEntity.Name; }

    public void SetCity(DbContext ctx, City c)
    {
        AddressCityId = c.CityId;

        // here I need some kind of refresh
        this.CityEntity == null; // true            

        ctx.ObjectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, this); // fails
        ctx.ObjectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, this); // fails            
    }
}

class City
{
    public Guid CityId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I want to create values step-by-step an save them against the database at the end.

```
using(var context = new DbContext())
{
    var city = new City(){Name = "New York"};
    context.Set<City>.Add(city);

    var address = new Address();
    context.Set<Address>.Add(address);

    address.SetCity(context, city);

    address.CityName == null; // true -> I want it to be "New York"

    // save all at the end
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

As my understanding, both entities exists in the context ObjectStateManager but did not know about each other (nor their reference). 
How can I achieve this without calling `SaveChanges()` in between?

Also tried with attaching the entities. But this causes `SaveChanges` to fail as of all entities have state `Unmodified`.

*Edit #1*

Currently I'm running this (simplified) code (which is still not working):

```
using(var context = new DbContext())
{
    var city = new City(){Name = "New York"};
    context.Set<City>.Add(city);
    context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

    var address = new Address();
    context.Set<Address>.Add(address);
    context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

    // at this point, both entities have the state `Added`

    // set FK manually and call update
    address.AddressCityId = city.CityId;
    context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

    address.CityName == null; // reference is still null
}
```

*Edit #2*

When calling `context.SaveChanges()` after `Add` it works, as of now, the added entity has it's `EntityKey` set.
Is there any way to set the `EntityKey`(EF6) manually as of the `Guid` is always generated by client and not the database?

Comment: I take it you use code-first  to design the model. EF has a standard naming scheme for generating relationships between tables/entities. If you don't follow it you need to use the fluent syntax to declare them in the OnModelCreated() event.

Comment: @MattiasÅslund No, it's database-first (in real). This is just example code to show what I'm trying to do. So, the naming is (otherwise than shown) generated and correct.

Answer (score 0):

During the SaveChanges method (and some other methods) there is invoked DetectChanges method that fixes relationships. Just call:

```
context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working. See my `Edit #1` to see what I have so far.